# How can I automatically start an application when the Samsung Tizen TV starts?

Tags: node.js, tizen, samsung

I would like to know if there is a way to start the application when the TV starts. I was doing some research and found two possible solutions in another question but currently none of them work for me.
The first was with Hotel TV, a feature that I found in the Samsung D Guides B2B guides. However, following the steps I found that my TV does not have that function. (Model: 4300).

Ref:
https://www.samsungdforum.com/B2B/Guide/GuideT3/TIZENH_GUIDE

On the other hand, another way would be to have a kind of script in Node.js but I can't make it work well in my case. Or at least not as I would like.

What options do I have left? Has anyone tried to do it?
The idea is that it starts only once at the start of the TV, then if the user closes it it is their decision and it should not open again automatically.

Comment: As an additional comment, this app that I want to start is made by me, and it works correctly.
I still haven't been able to upload it to the official Tizen store, but that's not something I'm looking to achieve because it's for personal internal use.